# Why KeyDown event handler not working properly after MessageBox.Show() in C#? Then how can I alert the User?

Tags: c#, messagebox, keydown, eventhandler

This code works fine only if I comment out the *MessageBox.Show()*.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e ) {
    if( textBox1.Text.Contains('.') && ( e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal || e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod ) ) {
        MessageBox.Show("More than one decimal point!");
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

What is the reason? and How can I alert the User?

#### EDIT

Then How can I alert for the wrong Key Press?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In KeyDown, a ShowDialog makes SuppressKeyPress not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326508/in-keydown-a-showdialog-makes-suppresskeypress-not-work)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085445/why-does-messagebox-has-an-affect-on-suppresskeypress

Comment: @demonplus Then how can I alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox1.Text.Contains('.') && e.KeyChar == '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("More than one decimal point!");
    }
}
```

It would better work on `KeyPress` Instead of `KeyDown`

While discovering I got a wonderful page saying about the [difference between the KeyDown and KeyPress events in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367865/3796048)

Comment: `Suppress` is better than `Handled`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557442/keyeventargs-handled-vs-keyeventargs-supresskeypress

Comment: @Shaharyar: we wont get Suppress in KeyPress and thus need to use Handled

Answer (score 0):

When you show message box, it leaves the focus from `TextBox`, and your code `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` doesn't execute at that time.

You should place your `MessageBox` after handling the input.

```
e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
MessageBox.Show("More than one decimal point!");
```

Comment: It doesn't make a change.